# Passing query as a parameter to udf function

Tags: sql-server-2008, udf

I would like pass a scalar valued select query as parameter to a function like so:

```
select * from dbo.ftLatestOrderLines(select max(id) from [orders])
```

The db server throws this error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Is there a work around to pass the query as a parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding another set of parentheses around the subquery...

```
select * from dbo.ftLatestOrderLines((select max(id) from [orders]))
```